# How can I change color of visited cgridview row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, yii, cgridview

I will need have changed visited row in CGridView on another color. What do I need to do to solve it? 
I found JavaScript or CSS way, but I didn't find any even approximate method.
I know what I can change visited link

```
a:visited
{
    color: #green;
}
```

but how do I change color of visited row? Maybe, does Jquery  have some method?

**UPD:** I have a CGridView table, I need to visited rows looked another color.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'columns'=>array(
    'title',          
    array(            
        'name'=>'authorName',
        'value'=>'$data->author->username',
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
));
```

How will have I done?

Comment: I don't understand the issue you're trying to solve. What exactly are you attempting to do, and what piece of code are you attempting to do it to?

Comment: @badAdviceGuy udp: I clearly explained?

Comment: There is no `:visited` for elements other than the `<a>` tag. You'll need to use JS / jquery to keep track of that. If you're wanting it to persist after page reload you'll need to use php as well.

Comment: As the others say, it's unclear what visited means in this context.  But after "visiting" something, whatever that means, if you can add a class to that element (which is easy in jQuery), then you can have different css for that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try so:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'selectableRows'=>1,
  'selectionChanged'=>'function(id){
        var selected_tr = $.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);
        $("#"+id).find("tr#"+selected_tr).css("background-color", "red");
        }',
  'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
  'columns'=>array(
    'title',          
    array(            
        'name'=>'authorName',
        'value'=>'$data->author->username',
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
));
```

Is that what you want?